# demo.html inside a Component

Tags: polymer

Is there a best practice for setting up a demo.html for a component? My component uses bootstrap for styling. Should I use the CDN in demo.html? That way I can ensure that the right styles are available if someone downloads the component via github and wants to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the elements I've seen follow the [element-boilerplate](https://github.com/webcomponents/element-boilerplate/) idea, which is include an index.html for demo purpose and host your project in the gh-pages branch on GitHub (that way you get a live demo right away).

See: https://github.com/webcomponents/element-boilerplate/blob/gh-pages/index.html

Comment: https://github.com/webcomponents/element-boilerplate/blob/gh-pages/src/my-element.html doesn't have the normal `<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
` statement at the top of the file. In the case of one of my components it is dependent on another component. How would one resolve that dependency?

Comment: Yep, the recommend approach is to create an import that contains the element definition and imports all of the dependencies. This includes importing `polymer.html` and any other elements that are resused. ([Example element import](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/creatingelements.html#createpolyel)) In this way, folks never have to load `polymer.js` directly in their app and all the dependencies are taken care of by Imports. [Example index.html](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/creatingelements.html#createapp)

Comment: We just made the changes to fetch Polymer from Bower instead of CDN. And also import `polymer.html` inside the element. [See #9 for more info](https://github.com/webcomponents/element-boilerplate/pull/9)